# Kotlin Constructor Crash

Tags: android, kotlin

In every single tutorial about inheritance for kotlin I've seen an example like this:

```
class SubClass(pref : String)  {
    fun theSubClassMethod() : String {
        return "The subclass method"
    }
}
```

However, if I use it as such, for some reason I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
                                                       at a.b.c.com.logic.SubClass.<init>(SubClass.kt)
                                                       at a.b.c.com.kotlinplayground.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:39)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/a.b.c.com.kotlinplayground-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                       at a.b.c.com.logic.SubClass.<init>(SubClass.kt) 
                                                       at a.b.c.com.kotlinplayground.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:39) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
                                                       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                            ... 16 more
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

The only way I can get it to work is if I do this:

```
class SubClass(pref : String?)  {
    fun theSubClassMethod() : String {
        return "The subclass method"
    }
}
```

Notice the "?" question mark in the parameter, without it I can't get the code to work, but the question is why? why doesn't it work without it and how come every tutorial shows the parameter without the question mark and they don't mention anything about it... am I missing something?

This is the way I use it:

```
val subClass = SubClass("ZZZ")
```

**Note:** If the parameter in the constructor is an Int/Boolean, etc it works fine seems to happen only with objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By defining it as `pref: String` instead of `pref: String?` Kotlin generates a null check in the constructor which is implemented in the `Intrinsics` class of the kotlin standard library.

The error is most likely because whatever is building the program is failing to include the `kotlin-stdlib` library. This means the required classes cannot be found.

Comment: that was it! Thanks... seems like Android Studio doesn't include the right kotlin dependencies.